# One observable, multiple Subscribers Rxjs/Angular share not working

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular4-httpclient

I a using angular 4 for one of my projects and i am making a http call to get the data. I cache the data when the data is returned from the backend so that for the subsequent requests i dont have to make the rest calls again and again.

```
getApplication(): Observable<Array<Application>> {
        return new Observable<Array<Application>>((observer) => {
            if (this.app&& this.app.length > 0) {
                observer.next(this.app)
            } else {
                this._http
                    .get<Application[]>(this.url)
                    .map((app) => this.mapToApp(app))
                    .subscribe((result: Array<Application>) => {
                        observer.next(result);
                    }, () => {
                        observer.next([]);
                    })
            }
        })
    }
```

This works perfectly fine. But if two calls go at the same time, i see there are two requests going in the network tab instead of one. So i tried share() to make satisfy 'One observable, multiple subscribers'.

```
getApplication(): Observable<Array<Application>> {
            return new Observable<Array<Application>>((observer) => {
                if (this.app&& this.app.length > 0) {
                    observer.next(this.app)
                } else {
                    this._http
                        .get<Application[]>(this.url)
                        .map((app) => this.mapToApp(app))
                        .subscribe((result: Array<Application>) => {
                            observer.next(result);
                        }, () => {
                            observer.next([]);
                        })
                }
            }).share()
        }
```

But this also, i see there are multiple requests going in the network tab instead of one. What has to be done to make only one call and share the result with all the subscribers ? Please help.

Comment: Hi I'd use a `Behavior Subject` which publishes its changes when `next` is called: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md

Comment: Share sounds so simple doesn't it! It uses `Subject` internally which only multicasts values to an observer if they were already subscribed at the time. So if something subscribes, takes a value and then something else subscribes it won't get that same value. Essentially `share` allows the first one to **steal**! `ShareReplay(1)` fixes this. I've found `share` most useful when you have a connectable observable that doesn't start until you've made sure all the subscribers have subscribed - then you can `share` all you want in that case.

Answer (score 3):

My first suggestion is to consider a bit of simplification in the code along these lines

```
getApplication(): Observable<Array<Application>> {
      if (this.app && this.app.length > 0) {
         return Observable.of(this.app);
      }
      return this._http
                    .get<Application[]>(this.url)
                    .map((app) => this.mapToApp(app))
                    .do((result: Array<Application>) => {
                        this.app = result;
                    }
}
```

With this logic you can cache using any logic you want. You have decided to check if `this.app` is not null and if it has some elements. But you could use any other logic, maybe dependent on the input parameters.

A different story is the problem of 2 calls issued at the same time. In this case you probably want both to `share` the Observable so that just one subscription is shared and `replay` the last result recorded so that you can return a cached value.

One way of doing this could be the following

```
private cache$: Observable<Array<Application>>;

requestApplication(): Observable<Array<Application>> {
          return this._http
                        .get<Application[]>(this.url)
                        .map((app) => this.mapToApp(app))
                        .do((result: Array<Application>) => {
                            this.app = result;
                        }
}

getApplication() {
    if(!cache$) {
       cache$ = this.requestApplication().shareReplay(1);
    }
    return cache$;
}
```

The trick here is performed by the `shareReplay` operator. The *share* part of it makes sure that the subscription is shared. The *replay* part of it, with a buffer size of 1, makes sure that the last result stored is always returned.

Then you may face the problem of clearing the cache once in a while. But here the story gets more complex and I suggest you to look at this very good article https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you call the getApplication() method twice? If yes, then you create two different observables.

Maybe you should follow publisher/subscriber pattern using subjects instead?

Comment: Yes i do call it twice in two different places .. Can you give an example on how I can use the pattern in my case